# Drawable Selector + TextColor

Tags: android, selector, android-drawable

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNcc1.jpg)

in the picture above, 2 button have the same drawable selector. the first when it is not pressed, and the other one when it is pressed.
How do I change TextColor depends on the state pressed
Here is the layout

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp">
       <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:id="@+id/l1"
                android:onClick="dialog">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Individual"
                    android:id="@+id/t1"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:textSize="18dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:onClick="dialog"
                    android:textColor="#000000" />

               <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SR 19.99/month after trial ends"
                android:id="@+id/t2"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:onClick="dialog"
                android:textColor="#898989" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonback"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:id="@+id/l2"
            android:onClick="dialog">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Family (Up to 6 members)"
                android:id="@+id/t3"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:onClick="dialog"
                android:textColor="#000000" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SR 29.99/month after trial ends"
                android:id="@+id/t4"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textSize="16dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:onClick="dialog"
                android:textColor="#898989" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

and this is the Selector drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <stroke android:color="#ff395d" android:width="1dp"></stroke>
        <solid android:color="#ff395d"></solid>
        <corners android:radius="60dp"></corners>
        <padding
            android:top="15dp"
            android:right="15dp"
            android:left="15dp"
            android:bottom="15dp"
            ></padding>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:state_pressed="false">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:color="#ff395d" android:width="1dp"></stroke>
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"></solid>
        <corners android:radius="60dp"></corners>
        <padding
            android:top="15dp"
            android:right="15dp"
            android:left="15dp"
            android:bottom="15dp"
            ></padding>
    </shape>
  </item>
</selector>
```

I want my code works like in the picture but I didn't know how to change TextColor

Comment: tv.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);

Comment: Abhishek when I press on the layout, Text Color changes to white

Comment: you have to set the change inside your onClickListnermethod  as **youtTextView.seTextColor(COLOR.WHITE)**

Comment: Click is different, I tried to find Listener for Press , but I couldn't.

Comment: update your java code here

Comment: I didn't write anything in my java code. All my code is only xml. You can test my code above and you will understand.

Comment: you have to change it dynamically at run time when you click on the layout

Comment: write something in java code and update here I will tell you where tp change

Comment: <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" /> use this in selector xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can change text color using below drawable file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:color="@android:color/white" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</selector>
```

Please set drawable like this.

```
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textColor="@drawable/selector_text" />
```

and You have to use `setSelected` property of `textView` to change your `textview` color in your java code.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to extend the parent layout which handles pressed state and gives a callback. This can be useful if you have for example an `ImageView` inside the layout and want to change tint color based on pressed state.

Interface:

```
public interface PressedListener {
    void onDown();

    void onUp();
}
```

Layout class:

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    private PressedListener mPressedListener;
    private Rect mViewRect;

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyRelativeLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setPressedListener(PressedListener listener) {
        mPressedListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        if (mPressedListener != null) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    mPressedListener.onDown();
                    mViewRect = new Rect();
                    getHitRect(mViewRect);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                    mPressedListener.onUp();
                    mViewRect = null;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    if (mViewRect != null &&
                            !mViewRect.contains(Math.round(getX() + event.getX()),
                                    Math.round(getY() + event.getY()))) {
                        mPressedListener.onUp();
                        mViewRect = null;
                    }

                    break;
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```